# How do I store application IDs/keys securely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

Developing the application in Ruby on Rails, hosted on Heroku.

Our application has several different app IDs/keys assigned by a number of different services (Facebook, Mixpanel, etc). We are now adding a payments system and so we are planning to use Stripe. We now have a Stripe app ID as well.

What's the best way to securely store these app IDs? Currently they are just stored as rails environment variables. All employees thus have access to all our app IDs.

Hypothetically if some one engineer goes "rogue" ... They could then poison their own DNS cache and match ourwebsite.com to some random IP address that they control. Thus, requests could be using our app ID but running transactions that we haven't okayed.

What is a good way to store all of these different app IDs in a secure/safe way? We are fine if one of our co-founders has these app IDs, but preferably there should be a safe way to access these app IDs without necessarily revealing what the IDs actually are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue that isn't solved with tech, but with contracts. Developers will always know more about and have more intimate access to a project than the executive team, and unless you are obligated to worry about it (i.e. to adhere to PCI or government security requirements) you shouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use Heroku, but have done something similar to what they describe here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

tl;dr: put your IDs into environment variables

Comment: “Currently they are just stored as rails environment variables.” Reading comprehension goes a long way.